# How to avoid Race Conditions when a restful architecture doesn't make sense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, race-condition

I'm making a website that I don't think makes sense to implement with a restful architecture (at least not the portion relevant to this problem), but it's causing some problems with race conditions across multiple servers which share a database.

My website has info about users of another product, so it has a Users table (not users of my site though). Users have many files.

Users and files are populated by an automated service, not manually on the site. The service posts the files to the server, the server parses them and gets the username from the file. If the username is new, it creates a new user row in the table. It then returns about the file to the service that made the request.

The problems I'm seeing are when race conditions when multiple requests come in at the same time for related objects, and it causes things like violations of unique indexes in the db.

For example, there is a unique key on username. This code can be a problem if 2 requests from the automated service for files from the same user come in at the same time.

```
var myuser = db.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.username == username);
if(myuser == null)
{
   myuser = new user(username);
   db.AddObject(user);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Request 1 will see that there is no user with username foo, so the if condition returns true. Request 2 sees the same thing, not knowing that request 1 already began creating the user, and when request 2 tries to save, it violates the unique key.

Is there a common pattern or solution to this problem? I know this wouldn't be a problem if the server was RESTful, but I don't think it's really feasible for the service to change the way it makes requests, so I'd like that to stay the same if possible. Right now, it just posts the file to the server, not knowing whether the user of that file existed already, or whether that file was posted to the server yet (it may post it more than once). Those objects are created if they don't exist yet, and if they do, the list of items is updated. But as far the service is concerned, it just wants to know certain info about the file, and isn't concerned with whether or not it already exists in my db.

I think it'd be too slow for it to try to create a user via a request, then try to create the file via a request, and then request info about the file in another request. Also, the service runs multiple requests at a time via Parallel.ForEach, and it'd be too slow for it to run it in a single thread.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is separation of concerns. If you have an automated service populating the data, then *that* service (or another piece of middleware) should be responsible for creating the database records. This shouldn't happen at run time in response to a request to your website.

Second, if you must do it this way, that is what locks are for. Each request to your website runs in it's own thread(s). So, if multiple threads need to access the same volatile resource (your DB) then you need to institute optimistic locking, so that the first thread in wins and any further threads will only be able to try to interact with that table or row (depending on the type of lock) once the first has completed its work.

Third, this is pretty much *exactly* what RESTful architecture attempts to solve. You can use ETags to version your resources so any attempt to POST to an outdated resource will return an HTTP error (409 Conflict) directing the client to refetch the original resource.

Comment: I thought about it and it seems like this would be a problem even if it was restful. Lets say 2 post requests end up trying to create a user at the same time (forgetting about files). The code would be pretty similar to the code in the original question. The save changes would just be inside the braces. In that case, wouldn't the same problem occur? Request 1 tries to create a user, and request 2 tries to create it also because request 1 didn't save yet? Would that need locks? Or is that the problem ETags solve (I'm not familiar with them)